# Difference between apache2 and apache2-bin?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, apt-get

My digitalocean server is running Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to install Apache.

When I just type in "apache2" to PuTTy, it says:

```
The program 'apache2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin
```

Yet on digitalocean's [official tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04), it says to install apache2 by using:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

What's the difference? Will it function the same with either command? What  will the differences be if not, and why would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the `apache2` package just provides a part of the Apache2 infrastructure, and doesn't contain the binary files. As you run the `apache2` command, the shell told you in which package that binary is located (in `apache2-bin`), but it doesn't mean that that's the only package you have to install.

In my raspberry pi architecture, the `apache2` package contains this files:

```
pi@rpi ~ $ dpkg -L apache2
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/apache2
/usr/share/bug/apache2/control
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/bug/apache2/script
/usr/share/doc/apache2
```

Please note that this may differ between different distributions. The `apache2.2-bin` package indeed contains all the binaries used.

You should install `apache2` as the tutorial says because it will install the whole infrastructure and will have `apache2-bin` as a dependency, so it will be installed as well.